# How to strip out the timestamps in the date field (not from a date field but rather a varchar holding date/timestamp data)

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have data that looks like this:

```
DATE
2019 04 19 03:00:00
```

I want it to look like this:

```
DATE
2019 04 19
```

OR

```
DATE
04-19-2019
```

The only catch is the field holding the data is a varchar so what I tried below doesn't work.

```
select to_char(DATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD') as dateonly, from table_name;
```

I've also tried using the following:

```
select trunc(DATE) as date_only from table_name;
```

But I get values that look like this:

```
 2019 04 19 00:00:00
```

I guess the above could work but is there a way I can get rid of the trailing 00:00:00s that result from the trunc method that I used above?

Comment: The problem here is that you have two date formats in the same table. You will have to convert to a single format in order to use the to_char function OR use regex to identify the format and apply the correct to_char format.

Answer (score 2):

If your data format is always like **yyyy mm dd hh24:mi:ss** then you can use following query to get the sub string:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('2019 04 19 03:00:00', 1, 10)
```

Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions196.htm#S

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do:  `SUBSTRING(x, 1, 10)`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes same result. I think 1 to 10 is best option. Thanks

Comment: @JohnWick in oracle the function name is SUBSTR https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm

Answer (score 0):

You have text. You want a date.

So use TO_DATE.

```
select trunc(to_date('2019 04 19 03:00:00','YYYY MM DD HH:MI:SS') )
from dual;
```

The trunc will remove the time period. And then you'll have your data in a proper DATE format so you can use all of the date specific functions offered in the database.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, convert to a `DATE`:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2019 04 19 03:00:00', 'YYYY MM DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual;
```

Then, from a `DATE` you can use `TRUNC()` *or* you can use `TO_CHAR()` to format it the way you want it to appear:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( TO_DATE('2019 04 19 03:00:00', 'YYYY MM DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY MM DD' ) FROM dual;
```

Hope this helps.