# How to convert from a date-time (in varchar format) to dddyyyy format (varchar)?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to convert a column with values that have a date-time style format stored as a date timestamp in a varchar field
A sample entry is below:

```
2019 04 19 03:00:00
```

What i ultimately want is:

```
1092019
```

What I am trying to do is convert it to dddyyyy format. After searching on this site, I found out how to switch from dddyyyy to a date timestamp ( i can use a to_date() function) but i do not know how to do the inverse. What would be the optimal approach? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What a bad idea to store a datetime as a string. Change this, if you can.

Comment: unfortunately those are the rules the architect of this brilliant database set

Comment: Looks like your are really a poor guy. 50% of all your [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9531146/john-wick?tab=questions)/problems are caused by poor design of date/time values.

Comment: PLEASE tell the architect this!

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit please believe me but if i could change the poor design of this database i would. hence why i have so many questions that are probably weird to you. sorry about that

Comment: @JohnWick, perhaps you should add a disclaimer to all your questions like **I have no power to change this bad design**

Comment: is this the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49760353/how-to-strip-out-the-timestamps-in-the-date-field-not-from-a-date-field-but-rat/49761002#49761002 ?

Comment: duly noted @DavidFaber

Comment: @thatjeffsmith no these are different questions, that is stripping out the timestamps, this is converting from a string thats in a certain format to a string that is in DDDYYYY format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String to date:

```
to_date('2019 04 19 03:00:00', 'yyyy mm dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

Then date to string:

```
to_char(to_date('2019 04 19 03:00:00', 'yyyy mm dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'dddyyyy')
```